# Привязки моделей. Свойства @Model не заполняются

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Решил освоить написание ASP.Net MVC3 сайтов. Читаю статьи и сразу столкнулся с непонятным поведением get и post представлений. Пытаюсь связать получение данных через @Model, но данные не отображаются.

Простой пример, создаю начальный контроллер:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Index() {    
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Index(getName names) {
        return View("Great", names);
    }
}
```

Класс для модели состоит из примитивного одного поля:

```
namespace TestMVC3DotNetApp.Models
{
    public class getName
    {
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

При получение GET выводим форму:

```
@model TestMVC3DotNetApp.Models.getName

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name);
            <input type="submit" value="OK" />      
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

При получение POST отображаем данные:

```
@model TestMVC3DotNetApp.Models.getName

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Great</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Model.Name
    </div>
    <div>
        @Request.Form["Name"]
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Проблема возникает в том, что @Model.Name ничего не выводит, но данные приходят и через @Request.Form["Name"] отображаются. В чем я ошибся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка вот в чем: вы объявляете **Name** в классе **getName** как поле, а для корректной привязки оно должно быть свойством. Замените в вашем кода модель на следующую, и получите желаемый результат:

```
public class getName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Если вы читали какую-нибудь книгу по ООП, то могли видеть там рекомендацию делать поля приватными, а доступ к ним осуществлять через свойства, которые есть синтаксический сахар для соответствующей пары методов. Тем самым вы сможете обеспечить корректное состояние для данных вашего класса и не нарушить его внутреннюю логику. Таким образом, поля не должны включаться в интерфейс класса - они должны быть инкапсулированы (между прочем, вы могли также обратить внимание, что интерфейсы в C# не могут содержать поля, но могут содержать свойства - из тех же соображений). Так вот исходя из этого механизм привязки моделей в ASP.NET MVC полагает, что вы следуете этому правилу, и работает именно со свойствами модели, а не с ее полями

Comment: После создания свойств все заработало и большое спасибо за разъяснения по этому поводу.